# [UIView setMyLocationEnabled:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d9d3c0

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

try to insert GMSMapView into my application everything i have done including inserting googlemap frameworks and creating api key but everytime this exception came out when i run. Please help me solve out.

here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

    self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;

    self.mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;

    self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}
```

> [UIView setMyLocationEnabled:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d9d3c0

Comment: Error is saying that you are trying to set myLocationEnabled on type UIView.You should be doing that on GMSMapView. Please show how you declared the mapView.

Comment: You can prevent this error using `isKindOfClass` method to check weather your object is that type or not.!!

Comment: Your mapView is a UIView object and there is no function for myLocationEnabled. Please check that your mapView object should be of type GMSMapView. I guess your mapView is an outlet and it has the class GMSMapView.

Comment: yes it is ..and i have assign the view to GMSMapView class using storyboard.

Comment: Put a break point and check in debugger using command po [self.mapView class]. Check what class you are getting.

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView; ..jassi here is my outlet

Answer (score 0):

Please check as below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad   
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  if ([self.mapView isKindOfClass:[GMSMapView class]]) {
    self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

    self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;

    self.mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;

    self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
  }else
  {
    NSLog(@"Make sure your object is GMSMapView because its not!!");
  }  
}
```

Comment: got the following error .. **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSServicesException', reason: 'GoogleMaps.bundle requires Google Maps SDK for iOS to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources''**

Comment: Have you used pod to add GoogleMaps SDK?

Comment: from where do i found that GoogleMaps bundle.. acctually the problem is that bundle

Comment: If possible put your code on Github and share the link. I will have a look on it.

Comment: It seems SDK is not copying perfectly in your bundle, so kindly check your projects `Build Phases`  and in that check `Copy Bundle Resources` tab for that sdk files are in there or not. Or also check `.a` file in the `Link Binary with Libraries` tab.

Comment: pods i have installed using [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start?utm_campaign=mdr-gdl&utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers) but i haven't found the .xcworkspace file

Comment: so u r using xcodeproj to open the project. Thats the problem. You should use xcworkspace to open the project after installing pods.

Comment: I suggest use `pod try GoogleMaps` and using pods install fresh copy and then try it.!!

Comment: so guys thanks for your useful suggestions i will install pods @Jassi again now voting up you both ..

Comment: @Jassi i have installed pods and got the .xcworkspace file now the problem i faced is **GoogleMapsBase** class not found but it is include in project ..what to do?